# Accommodating the Great Firewall of China

Tags: file-synchronization, screen-sharing

I work for a company that has a lot of remote employees, and we conduct a lot of business with file sharing services (namely Google Drive) and screen sharing services (typically WebEx).  We've recently started working with a company in China, and I'm looking for analogous services that are accessible in China.

My priorities are:

**File Sharing**

- Relatively secure.  I understand that nothing is perfect, but if possible it would be convenient to not have to encrypt the data going through the service myself (i.e. reliable built in encryption).
- User friendly.  I know that I could set up an FTP server somewhere, but I'm hoping that it won't come to that.  I'd prefer if it had a more accessible, graphical interface.  Also on the subject of user friendliness, it would be really helpful if both the English and Chinese versions of the site were decent.

**Screen Sharing**

- Affordable.  I believe that TeamViewer is usable from China, but I'm hoping there is something more affordable out there.
- Audio support.  This isn't a dealbreaker, but on the balance it would be great if the service integrated audio as well.  Saves setting up a conference call.

Contenders :

**File Sharing**: 115.com, smartfile.com

**Screen Sharing**: GoToMeeting, AnyMeeting, Blue Jeans

**UPDATES** :

- It seems like mega.nz is avaiable in China, so I think I'll use that for file sharing.
- After trying it, it seems that 115.com doesn't actually have very good English support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after looking around, I think I've found some services that will work for me, and wanted to share them with anyone who may be interested.  As of September 2015, all of the below sites were accessible in China according to

http://www.blockedinchina.net/

Screen casting/web conferencing:

- **Blue Jeans** : Probably the best choice for very large companies, it's very scalable and enterprise oriented.
- **AnyMeeting** or **GoToMeeting** : Both good fits for smaller/less demanding usage.  Probably comes down to personal preference.

File Sharing

- **Mega** : Seems like the most secure, but slow upload times and clunky share interface.
- **ShareFile** : Google Drive-esque sharing interface, very easy to get used to.  But no free option.
- **HighTail** : Very sleek UI, offers free option, sharing a bit non intuitive.